# How to pull books read using Facebook API to website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API but the books section is returning nothing.

This is what it returns on Facebook's Graph Explorer.

```
{
"data": [
]
}
```

Anyways all I want to do is have the books I've read and want to read to display the name and image (book cover) on my site. What kind of script do I need for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need the `/me/book.reads` call and `user_actions.books` permission. Also you need books in your book section.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "10101176585859437", 
      "from": {
        "name": "Philippe Harewood", 
        "id": "13608786"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-05-26T20:06:43+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-05-26T20:06:43+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Books", 
        "id": "174275722710475"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "book": {
          "id": "109248589093974", 
          "url": "https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Bourne-Ultimatum/109248589093974", 
          "type": "books.book", 
          "title": "The Bourne Ultimatum"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "books.reads", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    },
```